# Display category and subcategory into two column using php

Tags: php, javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Displaying category and subcategory into two column using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999761/displaying-category-and-subcategory-into-two-column-using-php)

How can i display categories and subcategories in this format using php.

```
  categories  subcategories
    ----------  -------------
    php         php4
    java        java4
    java        java5
```

My table is

```
cattitle  subcattitle
--------  -------------
acer       
            php
            java
compaq      java4
dell        
            laptop1
            laptop2
```

"acer" is a main category and "php" and "java" are its subcategory and so on. I want to display that type of structure using php. Also it is coming from one table. Table name is `categories` and fields are `id`, `parentid`, and `cattitle`.

i have tried this code..

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.
It requires that main categories have `parent_id` = 0 ...

```
SELECT sc.`cattitle` as `subcat`,
    (SELECT c.`cattitle`
    FROM `categories` as c
    WHERE c.`id` = sc.`parent_id`) as `cat`
FROM `categories` as sc
WHERE sc.`parent_id` != 0
```

... and this is another variation ...

```
SELECT sc.`cattitle` as `subcat`,
    c.`cattitle` as `cat`
FROM `categories` as sc
LEFT JOIN `categories` as c
    ON (c.`id` = sc.`parent_id`)
WHERE sc.`parent_id` != 0
```

This would work if your tables were structured thus:

```
id cattitle   parent_id
1  java       0
2  java4      1
3  java5      1
4  php        0
5  php5.3     4
6  php4.3     4
```

Comment: i tried this but not give the result correctly and give the result on the same line category and its subcategory.. i want to display category and its subcategory is in different line.

Comment: It is unclear how your table is structured. You have `java` above `java4` as subcattitles... This can't be right, when in the example above you show `java` as a 'category', not 'subcategory'. Could you clarify your table structure?

Comment: simply in the mysql table 3 field called "id","parentid" and "cattitle"

Comment: thanks for idea but this would not work and also i completed that task so thanks for reply my all friends..